# Show html file on server to iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I want to load one html file in iframe.If i am using it as locally like

```
iframe id='index-page' src='index.html'
```

It is showing the page properly. This file is now uploded on some server and i have the complete path of the html page on server.whenever i am giving tht complete path in iframe.The html file is getting downloded on desktop and nothng is shown on iframe.How to display the contents of that html file on server to iframe ?

Comment: Do you have the `<DOCTYPE>` tag set? Is the file actually `index.html` or are you using that as a placeholder for the question? Usually the browser will try down download a file if the `Content-type` header isn't set properly.

Comment: yes, setting it like <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: index.html file is on server now.